# Should you emphasise text within quotation marks?

Tags: style, technical-writing, formatting, punctuation

**e.g.**

**Bold**:

> Click **"Setting"** then click **"Options"**.

*Italic*:

> Click *"Setting"* then click *"Options"*.

Or even underline?

Or none quotation marks?

> Click **Setting** then click **Options**.

---

Which is better/correct/preferred?

Comment: What's the context? What are you writing this text for?

Comment: Step-by-step tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Microsoft Manual of Style for Technical Publications](https://www.microsoftpressstore.com/store/microsoft-manual-of-style-9780735648715), for commands on menus and buttons:

> Bold in procedures; capitalization follows that of user interface.

This is the convention we use for technical documentation in my company, as well, and correlates to your last example:

> Click **Setting** then click **Options**.

Answer (score 1):

Underlines are only for links; don't use them in copy for anything else (outside certain legal contexts).

Either use bold/italic or quotes, but not both. It's redundant. Which one you choose will depend on what's easiest to read. If you have many of these steps and commands, I would go with a bold or italic, as too many quotes gets visually exhausting.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen bold and I have seen inverted commas. I haven't seen combinations.

Simply say which you are going to use at the beginning. For example, I just found this in 'Beginning Android Application Development': "Code is presented in two different ways: We use a monofont type with no highlighting for most code examples. We use bolding to emphasize code that is of particular importance in the present context." (I haven't included their formatting.)

I realise that this code rather than which menu item to choose, but I think there are a lot of similarities.